# Difference between two usages of "two kinds"

Tags: difference

What is the difference between the following two sentences?

> **A:** I need two kinds of fuels.
>
> **B:** I need two kinds of fuel.

Comment: [This ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68599/this-kind-of-things-vs-these-kinds-of-thing) might help.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is incorrect. The second one is correct. Because you have "kinds", the object should not be plural. If your sentence was "I need two fuels", then that would be correct and "I need two fuel" would be incorrect.